# Disable loading notifications in Firefox

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 22, I want do disable the notifications, that appear at the bottom of the window when loading a page or hovering a link.

[image]

Is there a setting or a value in the configuration to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to `userChrome.css` below the default `@namespace` line:

```
#statusbar-display { display:none!important; }
```

The `userChrome.css` can be found in the `chrome` folder which in turn is located in your profile folder (see locations at the end of the post). This should hide the status-bar popup even though I wouldn't recommend doing so. If you want to keep seeing the information when hovering over a link and still be able to hide status information, you may want to try the following lines **instead**:

```
#statusbar-display[label^="Looking"] {display:none !important;}
#statusbar-display[label^="Connect"] {display:none !important;}
#statusbar-display[label^="Waiting"] {display:none !important;}
#statusbar-display[label^="Transfer"] {display:none !important;}
#statusbar-display[label^="Read"] {display:none !important;}
```

After saving your changes you need to **restart your browser** for the changes to take effect. If you're familiar with [User Style Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-style-manager/) (USM) or [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), you can of course use these extensions to make the changes. USM is a restartless extension; both extensions can mostly apply modifications on the fly.

---

**Profile Folder Locations**

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`
- Linux: `~/.mozilla/`
- Mac: `~/Library/Mozilla/` or `~/Library/Application Support/`

See [Profile Folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) at *MozillaZine's Knowledge Base* for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out where it would be in `about:config` but this [status-4-evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/) add-in can disable it

Tools - add-ons - extensions - status 4 evar - status - general

show status in: none; show links in: none

progress - location bar - uncheck "show progress in the location bar"

you'll also want to make sure your `ad-on bar` toolbar is not shown.

[here is the source code](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/192816/) if you want to try to find the `about:config` settings